# query in sql database

Tags: sql, mysql

How do we find the top 2 most populated cities i.e where no. of customers are higher than any other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your schema looks like:

```
Customers
  -City
  -SSN
```

You should be able to simply use `limit`:

```
select City, count(SSN)
from Customers
group by City
order by count(SSN) desc
limit 2
```

Comment: If you want to restrict the results in some way further, then yes. But this is sufficient for the question you asked.